# How to add a class in Qt Creator with CMake project?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I used to write code with Visual Studio, which is pretty easy to add a class. Recently, I turn to use Qt Creator to write pure C++ project and there are always something wrong with adding a class. The codes are like these:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "hello.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Hello H;
    H.say();
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I created a class named Hello and include it into the main.cpp, but when I compile it, some errors will happen.

[image]

So how to add a class with QT creator? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you added the class with `File > New File or Project > C++ > C++ Class`?

Comment: yes, I did it in this way. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, it is right and saves you time. What I see from your last edit is that you are using CMake. Is this right? If you are using `CMake`, you have to add the class's source files manually. Could you post your `CMakeLists.txt` in this case?

Comment: Yes. I used to write code with VS2012 and It's the first time I use Cmake.

Comment: Yeah there is a CMakeLists.txt and I don't know how to use it... I'm a truly green hand.

Comment: Could you add the content of the CMakeLists.txt? The `hello.cpp` file must be added to the `add_executable( )` call e.g. `add_executable( MyProjectName main.cpp hello.cpp )`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80016/discussion-between-kidsunbo-and-thomas-b).

Answer (score 12):

A really small CMake example project that uses a `main.cpp` and a `Hello` class would look like this:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

project(example)

# Useful CMake options for Qt projects
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

# Search desired Qt packages
find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)

# Create a list with all .cpp source files
set( project_sources
   main.cpp
   hello.cpp
)

# Create executable with all necessary source files
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
  ${project_sources}
)

qt5_use_modules( ${PROJECT_NAME} Core )
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "hello.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Hello H;
    H.say();
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Hello.h:

```
#ifndef HELLO_H
#define HELLO_H


class Hello
{
public:
   Hello();
   void say();
};

#endif // HELLO_H
```

Hello.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Hello.h"

Hello::Hello()
{

}

void Hello::say()
{
   std::cout << "Hello from hello class!" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Manual way : Edit the .pro, then add the .h and the .cpp in the "SOURCES" and "HEADERS" section like this:

```
SOURCES += hello.cpp
HEADERS += hello.h
```

Comment: Thank you it works and there is still a problem "**[cmake_check_build_system] Error 1**"

Comment: What does the problem mean? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry I did not know that you used CMake from the first post. This is the QMake solution

Comment: Thanks for downvoting... As the question does not mention CMake the answer is perfectly valid...